# Why is use of a certain @font-face causing text involved in CSS3 and jQuery transitions to not be visible in webkit browsers on mac?

Tags: html, css, macos, webkit, font-face

I am using @font-face fonts for a site I'm developing, and for some reason when I used AvenirLight instead of Avenir for the body font, it made the text associated with only CSS3 and JavaScript transitions (opacity:0 to 1) invisible on Mac webkit browsers only.

I still don't know why this is happening, and why it is exclusively happening in webkit browsers on Mac.

Lets try and figure this out!

Here is where the problem currently exists (when you hover over the two product images the product name should be visible):

https://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/

Here are my @font-face declarations:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirBold;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirLight;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Here is where I declared the body font-family that was making the text disappear:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    font-family: AvenirLight;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If I switch it to this, the text will become visible once again, but I would really like to use AvenirLight vs Avenir:

```
 body {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
        font-family: AvenirLight;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

Comment: Done and done @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snooping around, one thing jumps out:

```
@font-face {
font-family: AvenirBold;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: AvenirLight;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

You've got a TrueType font (.ttf) listed with format "opentype" (otf). I can't find a way to change it remotely in Chrome's dev tools to see if correcting this fixes it, but it looks like a plausible cause.

A ttf file is of truetype format:

```
src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
```

Comment: I changed it to an .otf font and it made the text visible in both Chrome and Safari. The only issue now is that in Safari it is bolding the font for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

for each font face declaration, use the same font family name - in your case, Avenir - setup your font declarations like below. You're better off using woffs for two reasons - one you can get your woffs down to about 20k with a good converter each to skim your pageload and the other is anytime working with workstation fonts - it may give you the "false" impression that your font is working when it's actually not - (think of the last time you sent a document to the printer and it came back looking not as expected ie. sent thru the print server, font not supported) Also, because of the whole copywright issue pre IE9, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=woff - IE really is the one you need to plan for supporting -for crossbrowser support, use eot files. If you are looking to get a font fallback for mobile android, apple 3g, use a fontkit service that you can remove as many glyphs as possible (eg. fontsquirrel) - however be aware that there are many professional fonts that are blacklisted from the foundry where made and even were you to get a hold of a legal, functional workstation license services won't allow use of service with font (making it super difficult to plan around ttf/otf).

Recap:
1. Font family stays the same
2. attributes for style and weight change
3. use woffs and either eots or (ttf/otf) in your kit
4. if you care about more IE support and not mobiles - include eots and (1) otf fallback for android, os 4.0; reverse for opposite
*5. if using sans-serif - don't forget the 's' in 'sans' (typo) your page will render ok in Chrome but not in IE and it will drive you crazy
*6. If using special google font styles (eg. &effect=destruction), please read docs first so you know who can and can't see
*7. ALWAYS, ALWAYS attain proper licensure documentation, especially for commercial sites! Don't put yourself in a compromised position by assuming your font came from a credible source! If it's not open license, and you don't have a copy of it you could be held liable.

```
/* font sytles
-------------------------------- */
@font-face { 
    font-family: "Avenir"; 
    src: url("your-bold-file") format("woff"); 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    src: url("your-bolditalic-file") format("woff");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    src: url("your-italic-file") format("woff"); 
    font-style: italic; 
    font-weight: normal; 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    src: url("your-normal-file") format("woff");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body { /* universal body style attributes */
    margin: 0; /* reset body margins */
    font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif; /* whatever your font family is of */
    font-size: 100%; /* universal font size across all browsers */
}
```

btw you switch fonts by calling up your selectors, whenever the attribute appears the new font takes over. If you'd like to stick with the font and give weight ie - p>.class {font-weight:700; /* doesn't switch font */} - only added woffs as an example, you can put whatever you want

from there your theme is doing something your plug-in wasn't designed to do on the mobile side. Basically you need to find a way to break out of the fixed constraint, otherwise your only option is to work within the given viewport. (eg if you were to set your fixed position to relative you see that your mobile is then scrollable, but no slideshow)

You might want to either contact theme support or galleria.io for help.

```
    </article><!-- product-details -->

    <div id="galleria"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="galleria-container notouch fullscreen"><div class="galleria-stage"><div style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="galleria-images"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; transition: none 0s ease 0s ; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;" class="galleria-image"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2;" class="galleria-layer"></div></div><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; width: 1349px; height: 638px; transition: none 0s ease 0s ; z-index: 1;" class="galleria-image"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2; display: none;" class="galleria-layer"></div><img src="MG_9400_1024x1024.jpg" style="display: block; opacity: 1; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; width: 1349px; height: 898px; position: absolute; top: -130px; left: 0px;" height="898" width="1349"></div></div><div style="opacity: 1; display: none;" class="galleria-loader"></div><div style="opacity: 1;" class="galleria-counter"><span class="galleria-current">1</span> / <span class="galleria-total">10</span></div><div class="galleria-image-nav"><div style="opacity: 0.5; display: block;" class="galleria-image-nav-right"></div><div style="opacity: 0.5; display: block;" class="galleria-image-nav-left"></div></div></div><div style="top: 562px; opacity: 1;" class="galleria-thumbnails-container"><div class="galleria-thumb-nav-left disabled"></div><div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="galleria-thumbnails-list"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 180px; height: 10px; left: 0px;" class="galleria-thumbnails"><div class="galleria-image active"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div><div class="galleria-image"><span style="opacity: 1;" class="img"></span></div></div></div><div class="galleria-thumb-nav-right disabled"></div><div style="visibility: hidden;" class="galleria-thumbnails-tab"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; display: block; opacity: 1;" class="galleria-info"><div style="width: 1309px;" class="galleria-info-text"><div style="display: none;" class="galleria-info-title"></div><div class="galleria-info-description">BOWDEN</div></div></div><div style="opacity: 0;" class="galleria-tooltip"></div></div></div><!-- galleria -->
```

If found helpful, please vote as I'm new to so community and won't be able to contribute due to 2 post restriction. Thanks

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I am sorry I already awarded the bounty. What is this code snippet here at the bottom? Is it just my code or did you edit it??

Comment: No biggie :) yes this is your code - if you'd like to replicate it so you can see it yourself - (if you have firefox installed) look up a firefox extension called web developer - generate source - lets you see what the script is doing, especially when it's tucked away and not apparent at all - it can be very frustrating... here's an example similar from a WP theme for a responsive site http://themetrust.com/demos/gather/ additionally thought you'd be interested in this: http://typeplate.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will update you on what I end up doing with the fixed constraints on mobile.

Comment: Hope you get the help that you need - I don't want to discourage you by barraging with WP links, but just in case Shopify can't help you - http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=revolution_wp - you seem to know enough about what you're doing to easily hook up a general cart plug in, or something more hardcore, lots of people making some crazy things for WP! You might also be interested in taking a look at ithemes.com if you're headed in that direction - best of luck to your site!

Comment: Haha I actually just moved our site from WP to Shopify, mostly because the shopping cart is so awesome and worry free. I had tried a few WP shopping cart plugins, and some are good, some are bad, but none offer the automation and worry-free experience that Shopify's does. If I were just doing web development for my company I would probably stick with WP, but since I am doing everything from customer service to fulfillment I went the least time consuming solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Arrgh!! I understand...that sounds so frustrating! If you're not getting a quick enough answer, look up the plugin on github, post your comment and point to your stack and shopify theme - and follow the plug in - that way anyone else following it will see your comment who might know enough about the theme and the plugin, or might have seen the issue and might be able to respond rather than waiting on one guy - the author of the theme. Unfortunately I know absolute zero about Shopify and the way their services works :(

Comment: @novicePrgrmr I don't know if you're still having trouble with this, but I came across a script that made me think about your situation - perfect for you: http://jquery-plugins.net/supersized-full-screen-background-and-slideshow-jquery-plugin This one is built for an iOS environment and works well - you'd be able to gut your shopify theme script and replace with this one - eb_p1 on twitter

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using "AvenirLight" with a `font-weight: 600`, which is a bold, and having a light font + bold together may not be compatible/implemented correctly with Mac webkit browsers. Try testing with a normal `font-weight` first.

Comment: I switched the font-weight to ``normal``, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if you find out why the embedded font looks bold. I ran across that issue before and didn't realize what was causing it.

I would try running your font through Font Squirrel to make sure you are embedding all the proper font formats (eot, ttf, otf, woff, svg) so your site is cross-browser friendly. You might have already done that but in your code I just saw ttf/otf.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator